# Consume Video RSS Feed in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am displaying `RSS Feeds` in my `MVC` application. .. The feeds can have videos too. The problem is that videos are not playing on my web page .. they display thumbs that are clickable and redirect to original video url ..

After searching on web I found a sample which displays video feeds from youtube (YoutubeAPI) .. but it was not so helpful because video feed can be from any service .. vimeo, dailymotion etc.

Please share suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of javascript video player like [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) or [Flow Player](https://flowplayer.org/) to play your videos. If you are using HTML5 - there is a video element which can do the same thing  Taken from http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-and-play-videos-in-html/26171

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>HTML Video Tag Example</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<object width="425" height="350"> 
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/tIBxavsiHzM" /> 
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/tIBxavsiHzM" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350" /> 
</object> 
</body> 
</html>

Read more: http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-and-play-videos-in-html/26171#ixzz39nDenmEN
```

Comment: thanks for reply .. actually RSS Feed URL will be added by end user .. so I dont have any way to track if RSS Feed is a video or not .. is there any reader which can manage this thing?

Comment: @NMathur - I am not aware if such tool exists.